# Running shell commands within AWK

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I'm trying to work on a logfile, and I need to be able to specify the range of dates. So far (before any processing), I'm converting a date/time string to timestamp using `date --date "monday" +%s`.

Now, I want to be able to iterate over each line in a file, but check if the date (in a human readable format) is within the allowed range. To do this, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
echo `awk '{if(`date --date "$3 $4 $5 $6 $7" +%s` > $START && `date --date "" +%s` <= $END){/*processing code here*/}}' myfile`
```

I don't even know if thats possible... I've tried a lot of variations, plus I couldn't find anything understandable/usable online.

Thanks

Update:

Example of myfile is as follows. Its logging IPs and access times:

```
123.80.114.20      Sun May 01 11:52:28 GMT 2011
144.124.67.139     Sun May 01 16:11:31 GMT 2011
178.221.138.12     Mon May 02 08:59:23 GMT 2011
```

Comment: As an alternative to shelling out to the date command, consider using the built-in awk function, mktime(), to parse a date out of a string.   Something like: sec=mktime($3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" 00"); if( $sec > $START ) ...

Comment: Is this a one-off project, or are you going to be processing megabytes of logfiles every day?

Comment: One-off. Its actually exam revision, and can't find anything about it in lecture notes. Easier to ask on here as answers tend to be better!

Comment: Pardon my editing error, if you saw this immediately, the array was incomplete. SHould be good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you have to do, its really not that hard AND it is much more efficient to do your date processing by converting to strings and comparing.

Here's a partial solution that uses associative arrays to convert the month value to a number. Then you rely on the %02d format specifier to ensure 2 digits. You can reformat the dateTime value with '.', etc or leave the colons in the hr:min:sec if you really need the human readability.

The YYYYMMDD format is a big help in these sort of problems, as LT, GT, EQ all work without any further formatting.

```
echo "178.221.138.12     Mon May 02 08:59:23 GMT 2011" \
| awk 'BEGIN {
mons["Jan"]=1 ; mons["Feb"]=2; mons["Mar"]=3
mons["Apr"]=4 ; mons["May"]=5; mons["Jun"]=6
mons["Jul"]=7 ; mons["Aug"]=8; mons["Sep"]=9
mons["Oct"]=10 ; mons["Nov"]=11; mons["Dec"]=12
}
{ 
   # 178.221.138.12     Mon May 02 08:59:23 GMT 2011
   printf("dateTime=%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d\n", 
       $NF, mons[$3], $4, substr($5,1,2), substr($5,4,2), substr($5,7,2) )
} ' -v StartTime=20110105235959
```

The -v StartTime is ilustrative of how to pass in (and the matching format) your starTime value.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, thats working nicely! I did try the arrays before but couldn't get it working. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach using awk's built-in mktime() function.  I've never bothered with the month parsing until now - thanks to shelter for that part (see accepted answer).  It always feels time to switch language around that point.

```
#!/bin/bash
# input format:
#(1                  2   3   4  5        6   7)
#123.80.114.20      Sun May 01 11:52:28 GMT 2011

awk -v startTime=1304252691 -v endTime=1306000000 '
BEGIN {
  mons["Jan"]=1 ; mons["Feb"]=2; mons["Mar"]=3
  mons["Apr"]=4 ; mons["May"]=5; mons["Jun"]=6
  mons["Jul"]=7 ; mons["Aug"]=8; mons["Sep"]=9
  mons["Oct"]=10 ; mons["Nov"]=11; mons["Dec"]=12;
}
{
  hmsSpaced=$5; gsub(":"," ",hmsSpaced); 
  timeInSec=mktime($7" "mons[$3]" "$4" "hmsSpaced); 
  if (timeInSec > startTime && timeInSec <= endTime) print $0
}' myfile
```

(I've chosen example time thresholds to select only the last two log lines.)

Note that if the `mktime()` function were a bit smarter this whole thing would reduce to:

```
awk -v startTime=1304252691 -v endTime=1306000000 't=mktime($7" "$3" "$4" "$5); if (t > startTime && t <= endTime) print $0}' myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the format of the data you're parsing, but I do know that  you can't use the backticks within single quotes. You'll have to use double quotes. If there are too many quotes being nested, and it's confusing you, you can also just save the output of your `date` command to a variable beforehand.